# What will be the query for this?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
    JOIN public.match m ON (s.stadium_id = m.stadium_id)
group
```

AS (

```
)
```

SELECT round_number
    ,stadium_name
    ,spectators
FROM (
    SELECT round_number
        ,stadium_name
        ,spectators
        ,RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY round_number ORDER BY spectators DESC
            ) AS rank1
    FROM t1
    ) AS s1
WHERE rank1 = 1

```
<br>
Any smaller query than this?
```

Comment: Hey, edit the question instead of adding info as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use window functions:

```
select ms.*
from (select m.round_number, s.stadium_name, m.no_spectators,
             row_number() over (partition by m.round_number order by m.no_spectators desc) as seqnum
      from public.stadium s join
           public.match m 
           on s.stadium_id = m.stadium_id
     ) ms
where seqnum = 1
order by m.round_number;
```

I don't see why aggregation would be needed for the inner query.

Comment: Something which I was looking for.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the max first

```
select m.round_number, s.stadium_name, MaxSpec
from public.stadium s
    JOIN public.match m ON (s.stadium_id = m.stadium_id)
    JOIN
    (
       select m.round_number, MAX(m.no_spectators) as MaxSpec
       from public.stadium s
       JOIN public.match m ON (s.stadium_id = m.stadium_id)
       group by m.round_number 
    )a on m.no_spectators = a.MaxSpec
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one more way to skin this cat. Throw your `MAX(no_spectators)` into a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
  m.round_number,
  s.stadium_name,
  m.no_spectators 
FROM
  PUBLIC.stadium s
    JOIN 
  PUBLIC.match m 
    ON s.stadium_id = m.stadium_id
WHERE
  m.no_spectators = (SELECT MAX(no_spectators) FROM PUBLIC.match);
```

That should do for an intro class.